# How to push code in one svn server to another svn server?

Tags: svn

I am working on a svn server A. And now I use svnadmin and svnserve commands to create another svn server B, by using below command lines. While server B contains no codes there.

```
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs test/
/usr/bin/svnserve --daemon --pid-file=/run/svnserve/svnserve.pid -d -r /ext/data/svndir
```

I want to push all codes in server A to server B, how to do it?

**More：**
I need a copy repo, which has read and write right.

Comment: Do you want a read-only mirror?

Comment: @uzsolt No. I need a copy repo, which has read and write right.

Comment: But in this case the repositories will not synced. If you commit  to `A` doesn't appears in `B` so the repositories will differ. The subversion isn't git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable repository mirroring and replication, use [VisualSVN Distributed File System (VDFS)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) or use [`svnsync`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnsync/). VDFS is faster and mirror repositories are writable. `svnsync`-ed repositories are read only.